# Can't run AVDM in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, virtualbox, haxm

I would like to run an AVDM.

I'm running Lubuntu as a guest on a MAC OS X host.

What i'm doing wrong?

KVM is required to run this AVD.
HAXM requires a Genuine Intel processor.

Unfortunately, your computer does not support hardware accelerated virtualization.
Here are some of your options:
 1) Use a physical device for testing
 2) Develop on a Windows/OSX computer with an Intel processor that supports VT-x and NX
 3) Develop on a Linux computer that supports VT-x or SVM
 4) Use an Android Virtual Device based on an ARM system image
   (This is 10x slower than hardware accelerated virtualization)